# ¿Iniciar proceso en segundo plano con C#?

Tags: c#, excel, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Llevo un rato intentándolo, pero no consigo ejecutar excel en segundo plano.

Lo que quiero es hacer un servicio que abra un libro de excel cada 30 segundos y lo cierre después.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {



            String ruta = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString();
            Process p = new Process();


            //Propiedades del proceso
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Exelcito.xlsm");
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ruta;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;


            //Iniciamos
            p.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 5);//Carga del excel + ejecucion de macros
            //Matamos
            p.Kill();
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 25);

        }


    }
```

Pasa que necesito que se ejecute en segundo plano y aparece en primer plano, esto se tiene que ejecutar en el ordenador de uno de los gerentes y tiene que ser en segundo plano para no interrumpir lo que sea que esté haciendo.

Comment: Y que es lo que te pasa con ese código? no se abre? no se cierra? Te da error?

Comment: Pasa que necesito que se ejecute en segundo plano y aparece en primer plano, esto se tiene que ejecutar en el ordenador de uno de los gerentes y tiene que ser en segundo plano para no interrumpir lo que sea que esté haciendo.

Comment: Intenta con `p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;`, aunque tengo dudas de que el excel se deje ejecutar en segundo plano...

Comment: Ya he probado, pero me da error.  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'El ejecutable especificado no es una aplicación válida para esta plataforma de sistema operativo.'

Comment: Ya,eso me temía...usando `Process` no creo que puedas. Tendrás que intentar usando `Interop`

Comment: ¿Interop? ¿Podrías ponerme un ejemplo?

Comment: [Aqui tienes como usar Interop con Excel](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects)

Comment: En teoría, con esto, podría iniciar excel en segundo plano? no me queda muy claro.

Comment: Si te fijas, hay una propiedad `excelApp.Visible = true;`. Si la pones a false no debería verse la aplicación. Pero no lo he probado, asi que no te lo puedo asegurar, tendrás que hacer la prueba :)

Comment: a que te referis con segundo plano?? que no se vea que se esta ejecutando?

Comment: Te has planteado utilizar un backgroundworker?, seguramente sea lo mas sencillo y te funcione bien

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero no lo he conseguido, me podrías poner un ejemplo sencillo para saber como funciona? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recomendaria que evalues hacer uso de las `api de office` o alguna basada en `open xml` para acceder al excel.

Recomendaria evalues la libreria `ClosedXml`

[Loading and Modifying Files](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Loading-and-Modifying-Files)

veras en el ejemplo que puede abrir un excel existente

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook("BasicTable.xlsx");
```

aplicar cambios y grabarlos.

Lo bueno es que al usar esta libreria podras acceder al excel sin tener office instalado local en la pc.

La libreria la referencias usando nuget

[ClosedXML nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML)

Comment: No necesito acceder a Excel, tan solo que este abra un libro y se cierre... ¿Podría hacer eso con lo que tu dices?

Comment: pero se abra visualizandolo el excel en pantalla? recuerda que un servicio de windows no tiene interacion con el desktop de windows por lo tanto si lanzas una aplicacion no la veras

Comment: No se tiene que ver en pantalla, tan solo tiene que abrirse, en el libro hay un evento de Open, y un script que se lanza

Answer (score -2):

Para esto crea un servicio de Windows:

Archivo>Nuevo>Proyecto

En esta ventana, en la parte izquierda seleccionar:

Plantillas>Visual C#>Windows>Escritorio Clásico>Servicio de Windows.

Para mayor información puedes ver el siguiente video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiAH1Qb0sjs